# Why is my formatting JQuery.Datatable formatting different to documentation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Why does my webpage NOT look like table at:

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

```
@{
    Layout = null;

}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
@*<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Employee Index Page</title>
</head>*@
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Employee Index Page</h1>
        <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Symbol</th>
                    <th>ActualPosition</th>
                    <th>AccountIdent</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @{
                    var categories = (DataTable)ViewData["MyData"];

                    foreach (DataRow item in categories.Rows)
                    {
                        string symbol = item.Field<string>("Symbol");
                        string actualPositionText = item.Field<long>("ActualPosition").ToString();
                        string accountIdent = item.Field<string>("AccountIdent");

                        <tr>
                            <td>@symbol </td>
                            <td>@actualPositionText</td>
                            <td>@accountIdent </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            <tbody>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
            $("#example").dataTable();
            })
        </script>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should include CSS file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
```

Comment: I put that link just after <body> but it does not make any difference

Comment: Maybe problem is with missed "/" in closing "tbody" tag?